# How to have the .isupper() and .islower() methods in one line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on some code that reads a csv file and gets the count of a searchWord the user looks for. The function shouldn't be case sensitive, so if a user wants to find the word: trampoline, it will catch TRAMPOLINE, Trampoline, etc.

I was wondering if it was possible to add in .isupper() and .islower() in the same argument, to simplify the code? I get the sense that I'm doing something else wrong though; just having trouble finding out what that is.

Ex. from the .csv file

```
I have 12 trampolines. The TRAMPOLINES are round and have netting 
surrounding them.

Trampolines are my favorite activity.
```

I've tried adding in both methods on separate lines of code, but am met with unexpected outputs.

```
def countingWords(word):
openFile= open('file.csv', 'r')
contents = openFile.read()
openFile.close

counter = 0

for separateLines in contents.split():
   if str(word) in separateLines:
      counter += 1

   elif str(word).isupper():
      counter += 1
   elif str(word).islower():
      counter += 1

return count
```

Currently if a user inputs: countingWords('Trampoline') the output will only be 1, when it should be 3

Comment: what you've written does not work how you think it works. Think again, what do isupper and islower do?

Comment: They return True or False depending on the outcome right?

Comment: The two `elif` statements increment `counter` if the word is all uppercase or all lowercase, without actually checking if the word is in the line.

Comment: @jackrabbit no. or well, yes, but you didn't say what you think the "outcome" is. Its not what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Convert both the target word and the line of text from the file to lowercase:

```
for separateLines in contents.split():
    if word.lower() in separateLines.lower():
        counter += 1
```

Comment: and then I presume you do the same for  .upper as well?

Comment: There's no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's overkill, but you could use a regular expression.  Why? It's probably a little faster than splitting and looping (not that it isn't happening behind the scenes anyway).  Enjoy - I wrote a little snippet below!

```
import re

data = """
I have 12 trampolines. The TRAMPOLINES are round and have netting 
surrounding them.

Trampolines are my favorite activity.
"""

def count_instances(data, word):
    res = re.findall('.?{}.?'.format(word.lower()), data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(res)
    return len(res)


print(count_instances(data, 'trampolines'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`islower` and `isupper` only return a Boolean as to whether a string is in lowercase or not. You want a function which will ***convert*** a string to uppercase. That is, a function with write/capabilities, not just read. Use `str.lower()` and `str.upper()`